# I am trying to show recyclerView in Fragment but I am getting an error

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, fragment

```
class FeedRecyclerAdapter (private val postList : ArrayList<Post>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedRecyclerAdapter.PostHolder>() {

class PostHolder(val binding: FragmentDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostHolder {
        val binding = FragmentDataBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return PostHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.binding.verimText.text = postList.get(position).lsi

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return postList.size
}
```

Here is the code written for recyclerView.

```
private lateinit var firestore: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private var _binding: FragmentDataBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private lateinit var postArrayList : ArrayList<Post>
private lateinit var feedAdapter : FeedRecyclerAdapter



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    auth = Firebase.auth
    firestore = Firebase.firestore

    postArrayList = ArrayList<Post>()
    feedAdapter = FeedRecyclerAdapter(postArrayList)

    getData()

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentDataBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root


    return view

}


   private fun getData(){
        firestore.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->

        if (error!=null){
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            if (value !=null){
                if (!value.isEmpty){
                    val documents = value.documents
                    for (document in documents){
                        val araziBoyutu = document.get("Arazi Boyutu") as String
                        val araziEgimi = document.get("Arazi Eğimi") as String
                        val panelBoyutu = document.get("Panel Boyutu") as String
                        val panelSayisi = document.get("Panel Sayisi") as String
                        val sehir = document.get("Şehir") as String



                        val post = Post(panelSayisi,panelBoyutu,araziEgimi,araziBoyutu,sehir)
                        postArrayList.add(post)
                        recyclerView.adapter = FeedRecyclerAdapter(postArrayList)


                    }

                    feedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.recyclerView.adapter = feedAdapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
```

The code here is the part where I define the RecylcerView and save the information.

I can pull the data, I can see it on firebase, when I print it with println, I can read it in the console, I can go to the page where the text should be written, but I can't see this data in the verimText TextView I'm trying to print.

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Where in your code are you setting the adapter? Please share that code.

Comment: I solved that problem. But now there is another problem. I am able to show the data I have saved inside the verimText. I debug with the println command and I can see the data I entered on the logcat. But there is one problem. Firebase always writes the first value that I entered, not the last value registered in firestore, over the verimText.

Comment: I updated the codes in part 2. All the code in my location app right now is like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "Firebase always writes the first value that I entered, not the last value registered in Firestore"?

Comment: Do I need to use the realtime database to show the current one of the entered data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: There are 2 databases in firestore, one of them is firestore database and the other is realtime database. Do I need to use realtime Database to display new information of new users created on registration screen in verimText?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemRangeInserted()` after adding post.

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview should be declared inside `onViewCreated` Method

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       val recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
       recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
       recyclerView.adapter = FeedRecyclerAdapter(postArrayList)
    }
```

Comment: My problem is solved. Now I can show the data I entered. But now it does not change the different data I entered. It saves with new data on firebase but shows old info inside textView.

Comment: try call to call the `getData()` method again after data insertion.. so it will fetch the latest data again

Comment: I need to learn something. For example, the package code of my project is xxx.yyy.com, but I try to pull this data from the fragment and print it to another fragment, and the package name of those fragments is xxx.yyy.com.fragment. Do I need to save my fragmented package name to Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

move this line

```
recyclerView.adapter = FeedRecyclerAdapter(postArrayList)
```

to

```
val post = Post(panelSayisi,panelBoyutu,araziEgimi,araziBoyutu,sehir)
postArrayList.add(post)
recyclerView.adapter = FeedRecyclerAdapter(postArrayList)//move to here
```